# UploadCollection: Non-working drag & drop functionality by using setUploadEnabled

Tags: upload, sapui5

I'm using UploadCollection (UC) for uploading files within my application (UI5 version 1.56.x). Everything but drag & drop functionality works fine. My UC has the property `uploadEnabled = false` because I'm adjusting the upload availabilty at runtime. With using `setUploadEnabled(true)` the UC enables the upload button which is perfect and I can upload files. Unfortunately I cannot drag & drop new files into the uploader and I don't know why.
Setting the property `uploadEnabled = true` within my XML view allows drag & drop file into the uploader. Where is the difference between setting the property fix within a view or using the method `setUploadEnabled` from the controller? Do I forget something important?
Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think i have found the reason for the described behaviour. I have used and additional `onAfterRendering` for the UploadCollection to react every time the collection changed. And exactly this `onAfterRendering` on the collection caused the described behaviour.
I have just rebuild the structure of my collection to use it without onAfterRendering and everything works fine.